# How to get song duration from currently playing track on other music player

Tags: android, android-intent, android-music-player

I need to get the song details of the current track playing on another app. I am able to get the following details except duration through the bundle extras. Anybody please suggest me how to get the duration

```
String artist = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
String album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
String track = intent.getStringExtra("track");
String time = intent.getStringExtra("duration");
```

Comment: I think we need more details.  Are you setting up a receiver?  Is your other app starting your song details app?

Comment: yes..Broadcast Receiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can get the song duration of current track which is playing on another app.I found the solution.

```
long milliseconds=intent.getLongExtra(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION, 0);
```

It is working fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

If the other app is also handling by you, you can set the data of duration with your Intent and can access the value from Intent in your activity.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    metaRetriever.setDataSource(filePath);

String songDuration =  
  metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);

long duration = Long.parseLong(songDuration );
String seconds = String.valueOf((duration  % 60000) / 1000);

String minutes = String.valueOf(duration / 60000);

Sting time = "";

time = minutes + ":" + seconds;
  // close object
   metaRetriever.release();
```